# My chrome extension stops working as soon as I add an import

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

The current code works and will alert when the button is clicked, but if I move `myAlert` into a different file and import it, it will stop working. Anyone have any idea what's going on?

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Getting Started Example",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Build an Extension!",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      button {
        height: 30px;
        width: 30px;
        outline: none;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="changeColor"></button>
    <script type="module" src="popup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
// import { myAlert } from "./alert";
function myAlert() {
    alert("hello");
}

let changeColor = document.getElementById('changeColor');
changeColor.onclick = myAlert;
```

Comment: Is myAlert the sole function exported? If so use import myAlert from "./alert";

Comment: result is still the same, breaks after import

Comment: Either use export function MyAlert() or export default function myAlert().

Comment: the contents of alert.js is export function myAlert() {...

Comment: The only thing it could be is your not importing the file from the correct path.Check both console and terminal errors/warnings. Make sure your setup is webpack/ES6 ready.

Comment: actually I wasn't using a bundler at all. after setting up parcel it seems to work

Comment: Without a bundler you need to specify `.js` extension. You should see an error in the correct devtools console which is different for the popup: right-click inside the popup, click inspect.